# How to return anonymous type from EF sql query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
var results = ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<T>("exec MyStoredProc");
```

The MyStoreProc returns 1 row always with 9 columns that are all int.

I don't want to create a class or struct for this one-time use type data.

What would be the cleanest way to do this WITHOUT creating a class?

Comment: "*I don't want to create a class or struct for this one-time use type data. What would be the cleanest way to do this?"* Well, create your own class/struct :)

Comment: why don't you want to create a type? it doesn't take a long time. if it's temporary or for a demo, just create a type real fast. if it's a long-time solution, definitely create a type for maintainability and readability in the future.

Comment: @kai Adding yet another DTO model object clutters up the overall solution, slows intellisense, more files to download/build etc. Our solution is currently very large and this will only ever be used within this method only and won't get reused so I'm trying to keep everything contained within this method.

Comment: if your computers can't handle the size of your solution I'd recommend upgrading your hardware or splitting your solution up into modules before sacrificing design. if you're this close to the limit, you're gonna hit it really soon no matter what, so it's a problem you have to deal with.

Comment: @kai How am I sacrificing design? Are you saying anonymous types should not be used? There is more than just one design pattern you know. Also, "Just upgrade everyone's computer" isn't practical since this solution is used by many. Your comment is not useful by any means, if you're not aware of a solution no need to comment further.

Comment: @user3953989 anonymous types can be used in a few cases, mainly to construct intermediary types in LINQ queries. they should not pass scope boundaries, since information is lost as soon as you can only refer to them as objects. this isn't so much a case of "I don't know a solution" as it is "you're using the wrong tool to solve your problem, this isn't what anonymous types are for"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that EF doesn't support returning any types other than ones that have EF mappings when using the ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery() method.

I ended up using a SqlCommand object and datareader with an anonymous type.

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically, you could create a generic wrapper method that implicitly detects the `<T>` type based on a sample value that you pass in, and then pass it an example of the anonymous structure you expect to get back. You could call it like this:

```
var results = AnonymousQueryWrapper("exec MyStoredProc", new {id = 0, name = "", ...});
```

However, I'd say creating a private class is not much more burdensome, and is much clearer. So when you ask "What would be the cleanest way to do this?" I have to answer, "Create a named type".